# C/C++ stdout/stderr catch

Tags: c++, c, stdout

I try to find a way to catch the standard outputs in a C++ application. This app is quite large, using third parties and may use outputs in both C or C++ ways (assuming there are std::cout calls as well as printf calls)

we can simulate by something like:

```cpp
void MyAwesomeApp()
{
   std::cout << "I am starting" << std::endl;
   std::cerr << "Getting a warning!\n";
   printf("With old style print\n");
   std::cout << "That's all folk!\n";
}
```

I already tried 2 approachs:

### 1. std::streambuf

```cpp
class MyStreambuf : public std::streambuf {
public:

    explicit MyStreambuf(const std::string& fileName = "" )
    {
        if (!fileName.empty()) 
        {
            _file1.open(std::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / fileName,std::ios::out);
            _file2.open(std::filesystem::current_path() / fileName, std::ios::out);
        }
        if (_file1.is_open())
        {
            saveOut = std::cout.rdbuf();
            std::cout.rdbuf(this);
            saveErr = std::cerr.rdbuf();
            std::cerr.rdbuf(this);
        }
    }

    const std::string& GetOutput()const{return saveStr;}

    ~MyStreambuf() override
    {
        if (saveOut) std::cout.rdbuf(saveOut);
        if (saveErr) std::cerr.rdbuf(saveErr);
        _file1.close();
        _file2.close();
    }

protected:
    std::streamsize xsputn(char_type const* s, std::streamsize count) override {
       
        if (_file1.is_open()) _file1.write(s,count);
        saveStr.append(s, static_cast<std::size_t>(count));
        // .... DO SOME MODIFICATIONS ....
        if (_file2.is_open()) _file2.write(s,count);
        return count;
    }

private:
    std::ofstream _file1{};
    std::ofstream _file2{};
    std::string saveStr{};
    std::streambuf* saveOut = nullptr;
    std::streambuf* saveErr = nullptr;
};
```

So I can call, for example:

```cpp
int main()
{
    MyStreambuf outbuf;
    MyAwesomeApp();
    return !outbuf.GetOutput().empty()
}
```

I can have the 2 files filled as well as the string, but without the content of the printf call (that remains in the console)

### 2.    dup2

using dup2 I can redirect all the stdout (and stderr) output to a given file. so I get all the contents of std::cout AND printf. but I can Only do that in a file that I have to read (an parse) at the end.
The application may run for a long time And we want to parse outputs during execution not waiting for the end.

Is it possible to have the benefits of the streambuf approach, but capable of catching also the printf outputs?

Comment: So option 1 disadvantage is that it will not capture C API?

Comment: How about named pipe? Create named pipe, `dup2` it to stdout and on other thread read everything from that named pipe.

Comment: ...note that it wouldn't event need to be a named pipe.  Just use [`pipe`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to create a 'local' `pipe` for reading/writing.

Comment: What are supported platforms? If you will use pipes the you need platform specific code.

Comment: Why can you only dup2 in a file? And why would that mean that you have to wait the end of the app?

Comment: Also, do you need a pure C solution, or are Unix/Posix solutions acceptable?

Comment: We would like it torun on unix-like OS.
Moreover on android (where the stdout does not really exists.
We would like to avoid threading as possible because we already fill the CPU with tasks!